# Change URL for Feign Client Generated By Open-Api-Generator

Tags: java, spring, openapi, openapi-generator, feign

I was using the `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` to generate feign client using:

```
<generatorName>spring</generatorName>
<library>spring-cloud</library>
```

The Client is generated as follows:

```
@FeignClient(name="${abcClient.name:abc}", url="${abcClient.url:http://localhost}", configuration = ClientConfiguration.class)
public interface AbcClientApiClient extends AbcClientApi {
}
```

In this, I wanted to specify the URL and also use a different configuration as I want custom encoder/decoder and okHttpClient. I can't modify the generated client file because it is generated each time the project is complied, so I will lose any value I set here.

I was not able to find any documentation or examples related to it.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!